# Touchscreen not working properly, need to connect laptop

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, windows-mobile, wireless-sync

Few months ago My windows phone's screen got broke so I replaced it with a cheap screen , now I can't type properly, some areas of screen do not work at all  , screen doesn't rotate on dial-pad and can't even paste no.s on dial-pad , so the thing is that I have to dial some codes like *123# (ussd) and 1 is not working , after dialing this code I have to choose option 1 (by clicking on 1) , 
.
So if there is some way that I can connect it to my win7 laptop /Ubuntu (bt/usb/wifi/remote)and be able to dial these codes.
Or remote my phone to my friend's android .
Plzzz answer

Comment: Sounds like you need to get the screen fixed, rather than find ways to work with a faulty part.

Comment: Is there a way to connect your windows phone and laptop and dial phone numbers using laptop,,,  I just dial these codes with this phone,, noooothing else